# If $E_i$ is open show $\cap E_i$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> **Question**
>
> If $E_i \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p$ is open for all $i=1,2 \dots, n$.
>
> Show that $\displaystyle \bigcap_{i=1} ^n E_i$ is open.

**My attempt:**

Let $x \in \displaystyle \bigcap_{i =1}^n E_i \implies x \in E_i$ for all $i=1,2, \dots, n$.

We know $E_i$ is open hence $\exists r_i > 0$ such that $B(x, r_i) \subset E_i$ for all $i=1,2,\dots, n$.

Let $r = \min\{r_i\}$.

$\implies B(x,r) \subset E_i$ for all $i=1,2,\dots, n$.

$\implies B(x,r) \subset \displaystyle \bigcap_{i=1} ^n E_i \subseteq E_i $ for all $i=1,2, \dots, n$.

Hence $B(x,r) \subset \displaystyle \bigcap_{i=1} ^n E_i$.

$\implies \displaystyle \bigcap_{i=1} ^n E_i$ is open

Is this okay? If there are any mistakes, can someone please point out to me where I went wrong and explain to me how I can go about improving? :)

Comment: looks good! Minor point, I think you mean $B(x,r)\subseteq E_i$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$. Hence $B(x,r)\subseteq \cap_{i=1}^n E_i$. You can't really say that $B(x,r)\subseteq \cap_{i=1}^n E_i$ before you know $B(x,r)\subseteq E_i$ for all $i$

Comment: Thank you!! :). That minor point is actually very important! :). Thank you for pointing it out to me!

Comment: If $\bigcap E_i=\emptyset$, there is nothing to do. Otherwise, let $x$ be any element of $\bigcap E_i$ (not, as you put it, of $E_i$).

Comment: Another big issue. The question should have said that the space is a *metric space*. Your proof is a metric space proof. For the more general *topological space*, the proof is entirely different, and uses the fact that one of the usual topological space axioms is that the intersection of two opens is open.

Comment: @AndréNicolas . Thank you! So the only thing O need to change, is let $x \in \cap E_i \implies x \in E_i$ and then the rest of my proof follows?

Comment: @AndréNicolas . This is from our first course in Elementary Topology in $\mathbb{R}^p$ that forms part of our Advanced Real Analysis course. I will fix the tag :). Thank you :)

Comment: Please modify as in the first comment, you don't want to say interior, open ball subset of $E_i$ is enough. And the question should specify that the space is a metric space. Or specify more strongly it is $\mathbb{R}^k$ for some $k$, with the usual metric.